# Play framework 2.4.3 evolutions not triggered

Tags: playframework, h2, database-migration

I'm doing the [todo tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList) of Play. When I created the evolution in `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql` nothing happens. I just get the Exception `JdbcSQLException: Table "TASK" not found` which makes sense.

I applied the evolution manually to the DB with `h2-browser` in activator console and after that it works. But the evolutions don't show up automatically.

application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password=""

# New
evolutionplugin=enabled
applyEvolutions.db=true
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# play.evolutions.enabled=false

# You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
# play.evolutions.db.default.enabled=false
```

1.sql

```
# Tasks schema

# --- !Ups

CREATE SEQUENCE task_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE task (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('task_id_seq'),
    label varchar(255)
);

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE task;
DROP SEQUENCE task_id_seq;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. I read the [migration docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24) and one has to apply `libraryDependencies += evolutions` to build.sbt.

Then it works like expected.

These are not necessary, they will apply the evolution automatically (without showing the `Database 'default' needs evolution!`):

```
applyEvolutions.db=true
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for Play 2:

```
play.evolutions.enabled = true
play.evolutions.autoApply=true
play.evolutions.autoApplyDowns=true
```