# Database Evolution not working in play 2.5.4 with java

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, playframework

I am trying to add evolution script in play with java 2.5.4 version. But not created evolution scripts like 1.sql in my conf folder.

I added below lines in my files,

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += evolutions
```

application.conf:

```
play.evolutions {
  # You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
  db.default.autoApply=true
}

And I have tried with below one's also,
    applyEvolutions.default=true
    applyEvolutions.db=true
    applyEvolutions.default=true
```

But scripts are not creating. Can anyone help on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added this line into project/plugins.sbt: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")

Comment: Having the same issue.  In development mode the evolutions are applied, but not in production.  Only the `play_evolutions_lock` table is created.

Comment: Similar thread here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561626/play-framework-2-4-3-evolutions-not-triggered).
In my case I had problems with SQL statement for play_evolutions and play_evolution_lock on Oracle. Please verify appliacji log file.
In my case two settings were enough:
play.evolutions.enabled = true
play.evolutions.autoApply=true